# mysql select with two arguments

Tags: mysql

I've created a table in MySQL with the rows time (unique), uuid1 and uuid2. My problem is, that I want to check for two rows at the same time.

It should look for uuid1 and give uuid2 as output, and at the same time it should look for uuid2 and give uuid1 as output.

**For example:**

My table is

```
------------------------
| time | uuid1 | uuid2 |
------------------------
| 1    | abc   | def   |
| 2    | ghi   | abc   |
------------------------
```

So if I query to "abc" should give as result as well the result 1 (time: 1, uuid2: def) as the result 2 (time: 2, uuid1: ghi).

I hope you can understand my problem :D Is it possible to create such a query?

Best regards, 
saltemohn

Comment: When you say 'row', do you mean 'column' ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Just try this;

```
select time,uuid1,uuid2 from my_table where (uuid1 = 'abc' or uuid2 ='abc');
```

Comment: I hope it is your expected result query.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to fetch a result when one statement is true, or if both are true? What is it exactly you wish to achieve?

Statement where one is true, but not both:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (uuid1='abc' OR uuid2='abc');
```

Statement where both have to be true:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (uuid1='abc' AND uuid2='abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is that the query select the unmatched column's value. The query below ought to meet that criteria:

```
select
    time
    , case when (uuid1 = 'abc') then uuid2 else uuid1 end as uuid
from
    my_table
where
    ((uuid1 = 'abc') or (uuid2 = 'abc'))
```